# Query DSL in ElasticSearch - term query

Tags: python, elasticsearch, querydsl

I am new to the query DSL in elastic Search. I am trying python to query the index in Elastic Search.
Below is the document I am trying to filter for using the query.

```
{u'_id': u'5',
    u'_index': u'data',
    u'_score': 1.0,
    u'_source': {u'attributes': {u'Accepts Credit Cards': False,
      u'Parking': {u'garage': False,
       u'lot': False,
       u'street': False,
       u'valet': False,
       u'validated': False},
      u'Price Range': 2},
     u'business_id': u'HZdLhv6COCleJMo7nPl-RA',
     u'categories': [u'Shopping',
      u'Home Services',
      u'Internet Service Providers',
      u'Mobile Phones',
      u'Professional Services',
      u'Electronics'],
     u'city': u'Pittsburgh',
     u'full_address': u'301 South Hills Village\nPittsburgh, PA 15241',
     u'hours': {u'Friday': {u'close': u'17:00', u'open': u'10:00'},
      u'Monday': {u'close': u'21:00', u'open': u'10:00'},
      u'Saturday': {u'close': u'21:00', u'open': u'10:00'},
      u'Sunday': {u'close': u'18:00', u'open': u'11:00'},
      u'Thursday': {u'close': u'17:00', u'open': u'10:00'},
      u'Tuesday': {u'close': u'21:00', u'open': u'10:00'},
      u'Wednesday': {u'close': u'21:00', u'open': u'10:00'}},
     u'latitude': 40.35762,
     u'longitude': -80.05998,
     u'name': u'Verizon',
     u'neighborhoods': [],
     u'open': True,
     u'review_count': 5,
     u'stars': 2.5,
     u'state': u'PA',
     u'type': u'business'},
    u'_type': u'business'}
```

To get this document, I am using the below filter query in python:

```
es.search(index = 'data', doc_type = 'business', body = {
'query' : {
    'filtered' : {
                'filter' : {
                            'bool' : {
                                    'must' : {'term' : {'name' : 'Verizon'}}
                                    }
                            }
                }
            }
})
```

But I am getting no hits with this query. Here is the result i am  getting:

```
{u'_shards': {u'failed': 0, u'successful': 5, u'total': 5},
 u'hits': {u'hits': [], u'max_score': None, u'total': 0},
 u'timed_out': False,
 u'took': 1}
```

But if in the query, i replace "term" with "match", it gives me the desired result. Let me know where I am making a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are specifying the mapping for the field "name" to be {"index": "not_analyzed"} it will default to being "analyzed", which means that that the string value will be 'broken up' when indexed to facilitate full text search.

The "term" query will look for an exact match of the text, but if "Verizon" is indexed as ["Ver", "izon"] this won't be the case. I'm not super familiar with the specifics of how text is broken down, but based on your example, this appears to be the issue.

A good starting point would be to use "term" for "not_analyzed" fields and "match" for "analyzed" fields.

Comment: Thanks! This helps a lot!!